# QGIS TIN Interpolation won't run (reports "Wrong or missing parameter value: Input layer(s)"

Tags: qgis, interpolation, tin

I'm trying to run the QGIS Tin Interpolation command, but get the following error message when I try to run the command:

```
 "Wrong or missing parameter value: Input layer(s)."
```

The vector input to the command is a shapefile containing less than 2000 points, and a floating point (real) attribute in the shapefile is specified as the interpolation attribute.

Here's a screenshot of the input form:

[image: Screenshot of Tin Interpolation input form]

The error message indicates that the input layer is either wrong or missing:

I've supplied the name of the input vector layer, so the parameter value isn't missing.

Therefore the parameter value must be 'wrong', but it's not clear to me why this would be the case.

Any idea why I'm getting this error message, and what the solution might be?

Comment: You have to press "+" button to add the layer and column to the table below the button. You can add more layers (point and linestring) to generate TIN.

Comment: Thanks very much - that solved it!